# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'any' property

Tags: soap, wsdl

```
$sh_param = array( 
    'SessionKey' => $sessionKey, 
    'ClientName' => 'QABudgetClient',
    'UserName'   => 'username'
);
$ap_param = array(
    'actuals' => array(
        'BUDGET' => array( 
            'Business_Unit' => 1,
        ),
    ),
    'integration_id' => 1
);
$headers = new SoapHeader('http://tempuri.org/', 'SecurityHeader', $sh_param);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers); 
$info = $client->__soapCall("GN_SET_ACTUAL", array($ap_param));
```

and it return for me 
"Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'any' property in.." set to string
$info = $client->__soapCall("PN_SET_ACTUAL", array($ap_param));

This is function:
GN_SET_ACTUAL(XmlDocument actuals, Int32 integration_id) on server

This is description from wdsl

```
<s:element name="GN_SET_ACTUAL">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="actuals">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="integration_id" type="s:int"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

this request works fine from SOAPUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <tem:SecurityHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:SessionKey>XXX</tem:SessionKey>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:ClientName>QABudgetClient</tem:ClientName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:UserName>username</tem:UserName>
      </tem:SecurityHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GN_SET_ACTUAL>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:actuals>
             <BUDGET>
               <Business_Unit>1</Business_Unit>
           </BUDGET>
         </tem:actuals>
         <tem:integration_id>1</tem:integration_id>
      </tem:GN_SET_ACTUAL>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can you help me? What is the mistake?

Comment: Ensure that you are passing "any" parameter in the request, as it may be expecting it.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, I'm getting the same error.